# MS Excel HyperLink a cell value to a corresponding cell with the same value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Lets say I have a Column of data, at the top of the column I have all my math calculations and I pull up important data points to the top of the sheet, such as (Max and Min data points based on a deviation from a reference value).

I also want to res-use the sheet for other projects which will need difference data and reference points.

### I'd like to have my max and min values link to the corresponding cell in the data set without having to scroll though 45754 lines to find the actual value....I want to write a hyper link so it automatically links to the cell with a corresponding value....is that possible?

### update below

### Thanks, the cell already contains `=(COUNTIF(B15:B13514, ">=" & G3))+15` so would the formula looks something like this, I'm trying to get it to dynamical create the link as the cell value changes. so would something like `=HYPERLINK(ADDRESS(1+MATCH(=(COUNTIF($B$15:$B$13514, ">=" & G3))+15),1),"Minimum")`.....I tried it as is but it has an error I'm trying to figure out

### Fixed!

Thank you very much for your help, my final solution was a slight mod to your link code thanks verrrrry much. FYI I  commented below, this data is a degrading battery, the microcontroller chokes at 1.4V which is that G3 is but we used different controllers with different brown outs and I didn't want to scroll through to find the exact data point!

```
 =HYPERLINK("[EOL 35C to 15C.xlsx]" & ADDRESS(COUNTIF($B$15:$B$13514, ">=" & G3)+15,2), (COUNTIF(B15:B1211, ">=" & G3))+15)
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, have a look on hyperlink function. (https://support.office.com/en-za/article/HYPERLINK-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f)

Comment: I must admit that I'm still a little bit puzzled about how you are going to obtain the minimum value with that COUNTIF formula... Anyway, after your question edit I understand that your data is on B15:B13514 interval so, if I correctly understand what you need, try with this and you should get your link working:
`=HYPERLINK("[nameofyourworkbook.xlsx]" & ADDRESS(COUNTIF($B$15:$B$13514, ">=" & G3)+15,2),"link description here")`

Comment: P.S.
Sorry for the delay, while I can use Excel at work I can't access to SuperUser

Comment: @Richard Will : Not having news, I rethought about it and had the doubt that maybe `=HYPERLINK("[nameofyourworkbook.xlsx]" & ADDRESS(1+MATCH(COUNTIF($B$15:$B$13514, ">=" & G3)+15,$B$15:$B$13514,0),2),"link description here")` could instead be what you need.

Comment: @Richard Will :  Ok, glad you solved then :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually test this now cause I don't have Ms-Excel on my PC (I use it at work) but I think that something like this may do the trick:

*Assuming that you use the first row for links and other and that data column is in the same worksheet starting from cell A2 and ending at A200*

You could put this in one of the cell on the first row (the one with links, etc.) to link to the minimum value on data:

```
=HYPERLINK("[nameofyourexcelworkbook.xlsx]" & ADDRESS(1+MATCH(MIN($A$2:$A200),$A$2:$A200,0),1),"Minimum")
```

The inner formula returns the address of the cell containing the minimum value in data column (A2:A200 in my example). You can do the same in a similar manner for maximum, etc...

NOTE: if the min (or max, etc.) value is not unique in data column you cannot link all cells containing it, only one of them.

Comment: Thanks, the cell already contains `code =(COUNTIF(B15:B13514, ">=" & G3))+15 `

Comment: See update above

Comment: I must admit that I'm still a little bit puzzled about how you are going to obtain the minimum value with that COUNTIF formula... Anyway, after your question edit I understand that your data is on B15:B13514 interval so, if I correctly understand what you need, try with this and you should get your link working:
`=HYPERLINK("[nameofyourworkbook.xlsx]" & ADDRESS(COUNTIF($B$15:$B$13514, ">=" & G3)+15,2),"link description here")`

Comment: P.S. just in case someone interested, this use of HYPERLINK (referring to worksheet cell) is not allowed with LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: Sorry, the data is a constantly draining battery and I want to know the min value just before or at the level in cell G3